# Detect IP Address of Client Passing though Amazon Load Balancer

Tags: amazon-ec2, ip-address, load-balancing

It’s important that my web site, which lives on an Amazon EC2 instance, be able to detect the IP address of the client. The `HttpRequest.UserHostAddress` property is of no value since this contains only the IP address of the Amazon Load Balancer which proxies the inbound request.

Researching StackOverflow led me to understand that using `HttpRequest.Headers[“X-Forwarded-For”]` would provide the client’s public IP address and indeed, I’ve been using this technique for a year with no problem. Until today.

Today I started seeing the IP address 10.116.146.52 being reported for a particular user. This is obviously a private IP address. `X-Forwarded-For` seems to have stopped working — but only for this one user. The one thing that makes this user unique is that he’s logging in from China. When he uses the same laptop and logs in from the USA, there isn’t a problem. The problem presents itself solely when the connection(s) originate from China.

Finally, I want to point out that I realize that `X-Forwarded-For` can contain a comma-delimited list of IP addresses as opposed to just one. In that case, I always grab the first one in the chain, since that’s supposed to be the user’s public IP of origin as noted in the Wikipedia article that discusses `X-Forwarded-For`.

Comment: You should be posting this issue on [AWS Forum](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/index.jspa?#) where the Amazon folks can take a look behind the curtains and get you some insight.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the user is using an additional proxy server that is adding its own `X-Forwarded-For` header. As you say, the header will contain multiple values and the first one is supposed to be the actual IP of the client.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/TerminologyandKeyConcepts.html#x-forwarded-headers has additional info.

Answer (score -1):

in: c:\coldfusion10\cfusion\runtime\conf\server.xml

Added

```
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve" protocolHeader="X-Forwarded-Proto" remoteIpHeader="X-Forwarded-For" protocolHeaderHttpsValue="https" />
```

to

```
<Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="false">
```

paste it under the first valve (around line 144)

works perfectly.

Comment: Seems to have nothing to do with the actual question.